# Is there a way to use A2DP/SCO bluetooth headphones in Ubuntu reliably?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth headphones that can be used in both A2DP and in SCO mode. Under Windows, I can activate both profiles simultaneously and I can listen to high quality music but when Skype rings, I can answer it right away.

Although I can use those headphones in Ubuntu, I have to connect them in either A2DP or SCO mode but not both and can't find a way to switch the mode on the fly which driving me insane. I can either listen to the music or I can use Skype and there's no procedure which will take under a minute to switch a profile.

Am I missing something there? Is there a way to use my headphones in Ubuntu like I do so in Windows or at least switch those profiles in the mid air without crashing music player and, more importantly, Skype?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using PulseAudio? If you use the 'module-bluetooth-device' module, it allows switching modes on the fly either with pactl (a command line utility) or pavucontrol (a volume control/mixer app). The line to put in your config or to pass to pactl (for A2DP) is:

```
load-module module-bluetooth-device profile=a2dp channels=2 address=YO:UR:BT:AD:DR:ES name=<your_headphones_name>
```

Then you can use:

```
pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.<your_headphones_name> hsp
```

to set them to SCO mode. However, pavucontrol has a much nicer interface, where you use a pulldown menu. It works wonderfully for me, and you can use the 'module-combine' module to make sound output go to both your speakers and your headphones. Also, it might be possible to load the module-bluetooth-device module twice, once with each profile, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Turns out BlueMan should run the first command automatically if pulseaudio plugin enabled (icon->about->plugins). But it doesn't work with pulseaudio 0.9.14, only with 0.9.15 and Ubuntu still have the older one. So looks like I have to wait again for a couple of months.

Comment: Ok, installed 0.9.15 from PPA, gave it a go. The result is - Skype doesn't work with that, it uses a lot of CPU and it can't hear me saying anything. But other than that this looks most promising than any other method.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be elegant but you can try adding a "voice" and an "audio" profile in your ~/.asoundrc file, but I think switching between the two would require you to restart the bluetooth service.

Might try to script it and put a shortcut somewhere convenient.

```
pcm.voice {
    type bluetooth
    device xxx
    profile "voice"
}
pcm.audio {
    type bluetooth
    device xxx
    profile "audio"
}
```

Comment: I actually tried it and it worked every second or third time, not every time as I want :)